# Button in Form tag will not submit or respond to Javascript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, laravel

I'm trying to submit a form for using stripe (button tag with a type of "submit") and I did some debugging (attempted), I know that the other elements within my form are working or else I would not be able to see the input that i've mounted into my form using javascript (card.mount). The button is literally the only element within that form that I can not utilize in any way, nor will it submit.

No matter what method I use, whether it be jquery or just regular vanilla javascript, I can not get this button to react to any events that I assign i (on click, i want it to submit the form). It refuses to listen.

```
<form action="{{ route('checkout') }}" method="post" id="payment-form">
    <div class="form-row">
        <label for="card-element">
            Credit or debit card
        </label><hr>
        <div id="card-element">
            <!-- A Stripe Element will be inserted here. -->
        </div>

        <!-- Used to display Element errors. -->
        <div id="card-errors" role="alert"></div>
    </div>
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <button type="submit" id="button2" class="btn btn-success">Buy Now</button>
</form>

<script>
//in my javascript file

// Custom styling can be passed to options when creating an Element.
    var style = {
        base: {
            color: '#32325d',
            fontFamily: '"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif',
            fontSmoothing: 'antialiased',
            fontSize: '16px',
            '::placeholder': {
                color: '#aab7c4'
            }
        },
        invalid: {
            color: '#fa755a',
            iconColor: '#fa755a'
        }
    };

// Create an instance of the card Element.
    var card = elements.create('card', {
        style: style
    });

// Add an instance of the card Element into the `card-element` <div>.
    card.mount('#card-element'); //this portion works otherwise I would not be able to type anything within the form. and I can use javascript to manipulate it,

    var form = document.getElementById('payment-form');
    form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        // here is the problem, I can't get a submit because the button I have in the form refuses to actually submit anything. It justs works like a regular button and randomly submits, ignoring the fact that it is inside the form

        stripe.createToken(card).then(function (result) {
            if (result.error) {
                // Inform the customer that there was an error.
                var errorElement = document.getElementById('card-errors');
                errorElement.textContent = result.error.message;
            } else {
                // Send the token to your server.
                stripeTokenHandler(result.token);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: For testing, I just added a script tag below and added the following:     $("#button2").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('does this work');
});
 this still did not effect anything much less, work

Comment: If you're adding event listener to the button then set button type button and you can submit you're form based stripe callback you can submit form `$('#payment-form').sumit()`

Comment: Now I just did that, and when I submit with the button, its as if it's ignoring the eventlistener. no preventDefault propagation, nothing. Honestly right now just trying to get the token to console log to I can continue on from there and set up the rest of the backend stuff but this just does not want to be responsive

Comment: is alert() working inside of `form.addEventListener` ? and place button type submit

Comment: no sadly, nothing. It's like I set the button to send the thing independently and it still does not go.

Comment: Did you tried `object.addEventListener("click", myScript)` ?

Comment: sigh, when I try to give the button an eventlistener, It tells me that, "it's not a valid function'... but when I attatch it to the actual form, the javascript is fine with no errors. this button refuses to function properly inside or outside of the damn form tag (desperately tried that)

Comment: At this point, my assumption is that the button is in no way shape or form associating with the form, inside or outside, but everything else functions fine, otherwise i'd be getting the same errors I would with the button, and I would not be able to do any input being that as I'm using that exact same javascript to form the fields necessary for the submit in the first place. I am trying to isolate that issue and make it so that the button can legitimately be apart of the form.

Comment: try to call your **button2** id in your **<script>** tag then issue a .submit() method: for example

$("#button2").submit();

Comment: still nothing. side note that when I remove everything aside from its class, it submits, and sends me to the route, but still, nothing.

Comment: Pretty late, but I removed everything, and I see that it actually does submit to the route, however the eventlistener isn't doing anything. it's like it's not actually waiting for an event on the payment-form itself. Doing more testing. But as of right now, Nothing is allowing me to grab an ID/Class that is in the php file

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it's because throughout the entirety of the project, I have a mix of both jQuery, or maybe my code was just wrong, but I did three things to aid this situation:

1. wrapped all of my javascript within $(document).on('ready', function(){}) and.
2. removed the name,type, and virtually anything besides the class from my button element.
3. rather than putting the form id into a variable, I used jQuery to assign the form directly. ex: $('#payment-form').on('submit', function(){}), I had to do this because when I left it alone using the variable regardless of all that other stuff, it still didn't work.

If anyone has an actual explanation for that, that'd be wonderful, but I managed to fix this issue and the submit is actually being recorded. Hopefully if anyone else runs into this issue, they can aid that.